# converting lpwstr to const char

Tags: winapi

I have made use of function **gethostbyname** function to get the host information.The function expects a const char * string but i have a  string of type LPWSTR and hence i'm getting the error as

```
 error C2664: 'gethostbyname' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'LPWSTR' to 'const char *'
```

i tried performing a type cast from LPWSTR to const char * as below but the compiler errors seem to go but its not giving the intended result .

```
  host = gethostbyname((const char *)resource.lpRemoteName);
```

i followed up google and made use of Cstring as below  for the same but the the function seems to fail.Please let me know the conversion .

```
    CString strFullName =resource.lpRemoteName;
    host = gethostbyname(strFullName);
```

Comment: You can do `CStringA strFullName(resource.lpRemoteName)`.

Comment: @RomanR : i know the question has been repeated quite a while in the forum and i did try the solutions on internet but they didnt seem to serve the purpose.

Comment: Thanks @RogerRowland that seems to have worked.